# node js send method

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to google this question, but couldn't find a decent question.
I am looking for a way to make this work:

```
  var testFunction = function() {
    console.log("it works");
  }

  send("testFunction");
```

I have no idea how to do it. I know this works in ruby though.

Comment: What do you expect `send()` to do?

Comment: Can you describe what you want to do?

Comment: Ok, i found the answer!! Sorry to bother people.

But for those who want to know:

        var testFunction = function() {
          console.log("it works!");
        };

        eval("testFunction()");

Comment: @Max please do NOT use eval read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/198031/1230908

Comment: @Max, I think your example is not thorough enough to see what you want to do... why not do simply `testFunction();` !?!?

Comment: @Mattias, thanks for the reference, but in my case its safe to use eval(). I use it to predefine a series of steps that have to be taken at deployment